# ZF2 checked option on a checkbox

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I'm having a little problem with a ZF2 application.

I need a checkbox in a form. According to this checkbox is checked or not, the value corresponding database in which there is changed: 0 or 1.
For this part, no problem.

If the value is 1 in database, and I open my form again, the box is not checked. I need it remains checked until the value is 1.

Could you tell me how I can achieve this? Big thanks.

Comment: Can't tell anything without looking on your code. This depends on your you populate your form (how you bind the object or such).

Answer (score 0):

in your template file use

```
$checkbox = $this->form->get('checkbox');
$checkbox->setValue($yourDBValue);
```

or be sure to populate your Form in the Controller

```
$form->populate($yourDbData);
```